# Maven install passes but there are tests failing

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, spring-boot

I am running a maven install for a spring boot project with multiple modules in STS.

I can see that there are few test cases failing but the maven install passes and shows build successful.

The tests are not being skipped, they are running during the install stage and the surefire reports are also being generated with failed tests but somehow the build passes.

I want the build to fail as the tests are failing, any pointers are appreciated?

```
<properties>
    <maven-surefire-plugin-version>2.16</maven-surefire-plugin-version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>

    ...
    ...
</properties>
..
..
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        ...
        ...
</dependency>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
            </plugins>
            ...
            ...
            ...
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Maven logs:

```
Results :

Failed tests: 
  MyClassTest.testMyClass:35 null

Tests in error: 
  MyClass1Test.testMyClass:64 » NullPointer

Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[ERROR] There are test failures.

Please refer to /Users/XXX/yyyy/zzzz/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ zzzzz ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [zzzzz] in [/Users/XXXX/yyyyy/zzzz/target/zzzz-1.0.0]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/Users/XXXX/zzzz/zzzz/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [232 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /Users/XXX/yyyyy/zzzzz/target/zzzzz-1.0.0.war
```

At last, it just shows all the modules build successfully. Shouldn't it stop building the war itself as soon as it detects a failure?

Comment: Post your POM. Otherwise it's just guess work. And post also the command you are using to run Maven.

Comment: Added relevant section, please let me know if you want to have a look at any specific section in the pom. I am using STS as IDE so running maven as "Run as" -> Maven Install (m2 eclipse plugin)

Comment: Could you also post the relevant portion of your Maven logs? What you're saying shouldn't happen.

Comment: If it helps, I have similar configurations for a spring project and it works perfectly. The only difference with this one is it uses spring-boot instead of pure spring.

Comment: Please post all properties, and also if you are using a parent POM. There are properties, which will continue the build even if tests are failing.

Comment: And the exact command which you use to execute the build.

Comment: mvn help:effective-pom

Comment: How do you trigger the build? Any chance to have changed the [testFailureIgnore](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore)?

Comment: @Joao Morais : This fixed the issue, thanks for the help. If you could put it as answer, I would mark it correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test phase in the build lifecycle is executed by the [Surefire](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) plugin. One of its options, `testFailureIgnore`, is used to execute tests and sucessfully finish the build regardless of the result. This is useful eg when generating metrics to Sonar.

One way to activate such option is using `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore`, perhaps you have enabled such option on your build.

Comment: tbh, with all the comments on this question, i am a bit disappointed it was so easy, and that OP didn't see this options on his command line ;-)

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation of surefire-maven-plugin, it does not fail on test failures by design. The reason is: surefire-maven-plugin should execute all tests and present the general statistics.

If you would like to save time, you can use this parameter:

```
<skipAfterFailureCount>N</skipAfterFailureCount>
```

where you stop executing tests after N of them failed.

maven-surefire-report-plugin can be used for reports analysis:

```
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/
```

Answer (score -1):

Any chance the failing tests are run using the failsafe plugin? This plugin does not fail the build on failing tests, as [documented on their site](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/):

> If you use the Surefire Plugin for running tests, then when you have a test failure, the build will stop at the integration-test phase and your integration test environment will not have been torn down correctly.
>
> **The Failsafe Plugin is used during the integration-test and verify phases of the build lifecycle to execute the integration tests of an application. The Failsafe Plugin will not fail the build during the integration-test phase, thus enabling the post-integration-test phase to execute.**

Comment: This is a pure guess so this is not useful as an answer. You should post a comment asking for more information. There is no point in being the first to answer.

Comment: No, not using failsafe plugin.